# Why can't I install MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I've downloaded the MySQL installer and tried to run it. On the Check Requirements, MySQL Workbench 8.0.20 is listed. I clicked and got this message in the requirement:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable Package (x64) is not installed. Latest binary compatible version will be installed if agreed to resolve this requirement.
```

I click Next and I get:

```
One or more product requirements have not been satisfied.
```

I click Yes, and MySQl Workbench is not listed. How do I install?

Comment: Search for [Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable Package (x64) is not installed](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads), and find the link that provides the redistributable ready for download/install.

Comment: @Luuk I clicked the Execute button. It seems to install the package.

Comment: I've go the same problem here.  I've got it installed but still says it is missing when trying to install MySql 8.  Perhaps the problem is the new Visual C++ 2015-2019 install package vs a straight up Visual C++ 2019 install package.  Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2023: The installer has a button to "download prerequisites" that opens https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

From there get the MySQL Installer and hit next to go to step 2. There, you can select only the "ODBC Connector" that will also include the redistributable. It is far smaller than the whole MySQL db install (e.g. 20Mb).

Answer (score 2):

The intuitive thing is to go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ and select the

Windows (x86, 64-bit), MSI download.

However this failed for me with VS C++ 2019 Redistributable required even after installing the latest version (2015-2019).

So I clicked on

**Go to Download Page** button which took me to:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html

and selected the 2nd, larger download (the 435MB file at this writing)

Although this is labeled (x86/32-bit), don't be fooled.  It includes both versions and will install the 64 bit version on a 64-bit machine.

The following link will download the current installer as of 6/23/2021:

https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-community-8.0.25.0.msi

If you are installing significantly later than 6/23/2021, I suggest you start at

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

to get the latest version.

Comment: Installing this way fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to install the 35mb 64bit version.  Kept coming back with requiring Visual C++ 2019...

Poking around found that if I went back to the install page and looked around the 32bit version of MySQL, there are two other installs.  I chose to install the 405mb MySql Workbench 8 32bit and was able to install successfully.  Albeit, mine was an upgrade from 6 to 8.0.20.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the previous MYSQL and download the (Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive
Debug Binaries & Test Suite) 499Mb version, when the error prompts on the screen simply hit No and execute. If the error persists, you might want to to download Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistribution manually and then continue the installation again.

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft visual C++ X86 or X64 from this link ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170 ).

Answer (score 0):

For those seeing this later, I had the same issue with a fresh install of Win11, new PC, and trying to get 8.0.3.1 WB, and got the same dependency error on VC++ 2019.  I followed all the same guidance above, and on other threads but it didn't work.  The WB installer didn't recognize the VC++ redist pack as being installed.

I went to my old PC, found the old version of VC++ redist, and installed it....voila, WB would install.  I used VC++ 14.30.30708, and it worked fine.  As of this writing the current version of VC++ redist from the links above, was 14.34.31931

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install 14.30.30708 version of Visual C++ (I am using a new Windows 11 PC) and trying to install 8.0.3.1 WB but for some reason the latest version of Visual C++  I had installed would not work.

I had to install the version 14.30.30708 and that worked for me:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/looking-for-microsoft-visual-c-2022/ac35251f-6ad9-4dd3-939a-c7c70b1f63b8

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the MySQL installer misbehaves when there have been previous installations. You can consider downloading and installing the MySQL Workbench app as a stand-alone app on [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). It only requires you basic configurations, and you should be good to go.